# ReSharper not saving and restoring Unit Test Sessions

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, mstest

While using ReShaper's test runner to run MSTests, with this option set to true for

**ReSharper  > Options > Unit Testing > Save and restore Unit Test Sessions**

Upon closing and reopening solution, the test session results are wiped out entirely.

One has to rerun lengthy regression tests again.

Any ideas as to how to fix this option's intended behaviour would be much appreciated.

It would be useful to know how and where ReSharper saves session data between Visual Studio opening/closing. The save and restore feature is too black-box so to speak. Would be better to locate and restore from a session file.

Answer (score 2):

"Save and restore Unit Test Sessions" just saves the *selection* of the unit tests, not the results (red/green/execution times).

The unit test sessions are stored in the ".DotSettings.user" file next to your sln-file.

**EDIT:** This is outdated information. Nowadays ReSharper stores the sessions somewhere else. I think as part of the "solution cache".

Comment: My Unit Test Sessions are correctly preserved, but when I open the ".DotSettings.user" file there is nothing in there.